# Error Filtering Template

Tags: error, magento2.2, vendor

After upgrading my server from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 my frontend only displays this error:

```
Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/root/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php on line 262
```

Now I looked into ProductsList.php and looked at lines 262 - 270 but it does not make sense to me why it would output an error...

Heres the code from ProductsList.php:

```
            foreach ($conditions as $key => $condition) {
        if (!empty($condition['attribute'])
            && in_array($condition['attribute'], ['special_from_date', 'special_to_date'])
        ) {
            $conditions[$key]['value'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($condition['value']));
        }
    }

    $this->rule->loadPost(['conditions' => $conditions]);
    return $this->rule->getConditions();
}
```

Can anyone offer some advice on this issue?

Comment: Can you var_dump the $conditions variable and post the output?

Comment: I just got into that. Did you find why ? _$conditions_ is _null_ in my case. Maybe they added some automatic thing on save, because _ProductList.php_ is not changed, even on 2.3. I can't believe the guy who had the _foreach_ did not make a _is_array_

Comment: Sorry, I think what I did was just to update to 2.2.1 and the problem luckily disappeared.